# How to convert a list of objects into a simple list, selecting a single attribute from the list of objects?

Tags: terraform

Suppose we have this:

```
whitelist = [
  { 
     cidr = "10.0.0.0/8",
     desc = "customer1"
  },
  {
     cidr = "10.1.0.0/8",
     desc = "customer2"
  },...
]
```

How do I make a simple list whitelist_cidrs which is simply:

```
whitelist_cidrs = [ "10.0.0.0/8", "0.1.0.0/8",...]
```

How do I convert a list of objects to a simple list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) is what you are probably looking for:

```
locals {
  whitelist = [
    {
      cidr = "10.0.0.0/8",
      desc = "customer1"
    },
    {
      cidr = "10.1.0.0/8",
      desc = "customer2"
    }
  ]
}

output "whitelist_cidrs" {
  value = [for p in local.whitelist : p.cidr]
}
```

Output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + whitelist_cidrs = [
      + "10.0.0.0/8",
      + "10.1.0.0/8",
    ]
```

Comment: my bad - bad data.  This is a correct solution!